# Scroll down whole activity with one element and a list view in Android

Tags: java, android

Let me explain my problem. I have a layout such as:

```
<LinearLayout ... >  (vertical)

    <FixedHeightLayout ... />    (let's say the middle of the whole screen height)
    <GridView ... />             (large grid of items)

</LinearLayout>
```

That is, I have a vertically oriented linear layout with two items: a fixed height shape and a grid view. I do need to be able to scroll down to the end of the whole activity but not only the list view. The thing is that I can scroll the list view but I need the fixed height layout to disappear.

How can I achieve this? Sorry but it's difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "fixed height layout" as a header to your `ListView` with [`addHeaderView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29):

```
listView.addHeaderView(R.layout.fixedHeightLayout);
```

Comment: Ahmad, thank u very much. Should I add the header view before or after setting the list view adapter?

Comment: Before setting the adapter @DídacPérez.

Comment: Thanks. Ahmad, I have a very serious problem. I was wrong, I am using a GridView not a ListView...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to add headers to GridViews.

Comment: Okay, and another trick to solve my problem? What about putting my grid view as the single item of a list view which header is my fixed height view?